# Laravel vite not working in production environment

Tags: laravel, vite

I using Laravel 9 and vite^3.0.4.
I did all kind of confirmation and migration it's working fine in `npm run dev` but not working in `npm run build`.

```
resources/vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css
```

My vite configuration

> vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/core/app-root.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ],

   server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    }
});
```

This file is exist and working in development environment. While I run npm run build I got this error.
[image]

```
npm run dev
```

terminal
[image]

npm run build

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting resources/vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css
 in your input array or include it in any of your CSS files that are already working?

Comment: Yes, already I did  

@vite([
        'resources/vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css'
    ])

Comment: Unfortunately no CSS file is loading

Comment: You only have `app.css` in your `vite.config.js` so I would expect that one (and only that one) to work.

Comment: After moving all css & js file from blade file to vite.config.js now I got CROS error & file not located error 404.
https://ibb.co/yhZtcr2

Comment: Any file you reference via `@vite` you also need to include in `vite.config.js` **you need both**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251804/discussion-between-tanmoy-biswas-and-apokryfos).

Comment: So you mean I have to keep css & js files in both side. vite.config.js & blade files?
I did that I still errors are same.